# Luatex vs Xelatex automatic graphs drawing

Tags: xetex, luatex, graphs

I have question about automatic graphs drawing with latex. So I want to use

> \usegdlibrary

To generate my graphs layout automatically without my interruption where to put states and nodes. Is it possible to use this library with xelatex? Or I should use Luatex. Where you offer to get luatex and what is the difference between luatex and xelatex?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=0.75cm}]
\graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=0.5in, sibling distance=0.5in]
    {
        4 -> { 
          3 -> { 1 -> { 5, " " }, 2,2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 }
        } 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is completely unclear, `\usegdlibrary` is not a standard command so presumably it is defined in some package somewhere, you should at least state that much and preferably fix the example so people can test any answers.

Comment: I am at thinking phase, where to start, but okey I have one example.

Comment: The new example just makes `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \usetikzlibrary`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For example I would like to use **\usegdlibrary{force}**, with code: `\tikz \graph [random seed=10, spring layout] {
a -- {b, c, d} -- e -- f -- {g,h} -- {a,b,e};
}` , But it is throwing errors for unknown command.

Comment: If you want to ask about an error make an example that makes that error and post the exact error that you get, The example as posted still just makes an error that  `\usetikzlibrary` is not defined. Your initial version didn't even give any indication that you were using tikz at all.

Answer (score 5):

If you run your example (after adding `\usepackage{tikz}`) you get a pretty clear error message:

```
! Package pgf Error: You need to run LuaTeX to use the graph drawing library.
```

You cannot use `xelatex`. That library uses a lot of Lua code I think, so you need to run `lualatex`.

Running the code with `lualatex` gives

[image]

Comment: When I run LuaTex it is generating me only text, not graph :) Maybe something is wrong with my LuaTex?

Comment: I added the output I get to my answer. You did add `\usepackage{tikz}` at the start of the preamble?

Comment: Okey, I found my mistake I was using Luatex, not Lualatex :)